# Probability problem (click to read problem)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two radioactive sources, $A$ ($Po(2)$) and $B$ ($Po(4)$) emit every minute a number of particles, independently of each other. A detector detects the particles from both $A$ and $B$ in the duration of a minute to be equal to $3$. What is the probability that at least one of the particles have come from $A$.

**My solution:**

Lets call:

$X_A$ the number of particles from $A$

$X_B$ the number of particles from $B$.

The probability that at least one has come from $A$ is:

$P(X_A = 1, X_B = 2) + P(X_A = 2, X_B =1) + P(X_A = 3, X_B = 0) $

or because of independence

$P(X_A = 1)*P(X_B = 2) + P(X_A = 2)*P(X_B =1) + P(X_A = 3)*P(X_B = 0) $

Why don't I get the right answer (which is 0.7)?

Comment: Are all events equally likely?

Comment: It doesn't say. It just says that they are independent events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to find a conditional probability:

\begin{align}
P(\text{At least $1$ from $A\mid A$ and $B$ emitted $3$}) &= \dfrac{P(X_A=1,X_B=2) + P(X_A=2,X_B=1) + P(X_A=3,X_B=0)}{P(X_{A+B}=3)}
\end{align}

Note that $X_{A+B}\sim\text{Poisson}(6)$.

Comment: thanks I calculated only the first part